# Relationship of a class which creates object to the created object UML

Tags: class, uml, relationship, class-diagram, object-oriented-analysis

I am not sure which relationship between classes would be adequate for a class which returns a created object or gets an object as parameter(see uploaded picture). I guess that aggregation/composition is wrong since Class1 does not own the object/does not have it as an attribute. Also I think that an association is wrong since Class1 does not refers to a pointer.

Thank you in advance for any answers.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

That would simply be dependencies:

[image]

An association is created in case you have a stronger relation between classes. That is either one is holding a more permanent relation (in form of an attribute) rather than a temporary one like in using them as passing parameter or return parameter. From an UML point of view an association is basically a stronger form of a dependency.

Note that the untyped attributes you sketched are of no interest in this context and I just left them out.

According to a comment of [@www.admiraalit.nl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5483079/www-admiraalit-nl): If `Class1` creates new instances of `Class3`, the dependency may have the `≪create≫` stereotype, see table 22.1 of the UML spec. v2.5.1. In that case the dependency would be a usage (chap. 7.8.23) which is just a *bit* stronger

Comment: One small addition: If Class1 creates new instances of Class3, the dependency may have the ≪create≫ stereotype, see table 22.1 of the UML spec. v2.5.1. This comment may be relevant because the question was about "a class which returns a created object".

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Thank. I didn't know that existed, but also never really had a need for it. Anyway, I'll add that info :-)

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl I just tried with EA (my standard tool) and although the UML standard says _A conforming tool shall support all of the stereotypes in the Standard Profile_  they do not offer ≪create≫ (and a couple of other stereotypes seem to be missing too).

Comment: You can't select ≪create≫, but you can type "create" in the stereotype field and the effect is the same.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl I know, but a stereotype must belong to a profile. And that "free typing" in EA is plain wrong. Diffent story and a can of worms :-)

Answer (score 0):

> a class which returns a created object or gets an object as parameter(see uploaded picture)

you mean for a class having an operation returning ... and an other getting ...

> I guess that aggregation/composition is wrong since Class1 does not own the object/does not have it as an attribute

you are right

> Also I think that an association is wrong since Class1 does not refers to a pointer.

whatever by pointer or by value (which is target language dependent) an association is not right because there is no attribute in *Class1* whose type is *Class2* or *Class3*

The only possible relation between *Class1* and *Class2* or *Class3* seems to be a dependency, but to have them does not have a real plus value, the profile of the operations already give that information